# Best practice for an enum in a class changing a return of a function

Tags: c#, if-statement, enums, switch-statement, organization

So for instance you have an object with a type for sounds, and based on the enum a particular function will do play a different sound depending on the type

```cs
public enum ObjectType{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}

public class Object{
    public ObjectType type;
    public Sound sound;

    private void DoThing(){

        if(type == ObjectType.Type1){
            sound = Load("sounds/sound1");
        }
        if(type == ObjectType.Type2){
            sound = Load("sounds/sound2");
        }
        //etc...

    }

}
```

I guess my question is, when this enum will grow larger in size into the tens or hundreds, what's the best practice to organize and test against the enum to return another value?
Should I be using a switch case rather than a bunch of if tests? Mostly just regarding organization, these functions aren't really resource heavy and won't be using a lot of computation, so performance isn't really my concern, mostly readability.

Comment: As a polite nudge, it helps if you post properly formatted, syntactically correct code. The code above would not compile as 'type.Type1' is not correct code and the formatting makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

If you have hundreds of values an enum might not be the best representation, but in general if you have a lot of items you need to fetch based on some value you would build a lookup table.

You can build that table once, then it's just a single line of code to fetch the correct item based on the enum value in question.

```
public class MyObject
{
    private ObjectType type;
    private Sound sound;

    private static Dictionary<ObjectType, Sound> soundLookup = new Dictionary<ObjectType, Sound>()
    {
        { ObjectType.Type1, Load("sounds/sound1") },
        { ObjectType.Type2, Load("sounds/sound2") },
        { ObjectType.Type3, Load("sounds/sound3") },
        // etc.
        { ObjectType.Type99, Load("sounds/sound99") },
    };

    public MyObject(ObjectType objectType)
    {
        this.type = objectType;
        this.sound = soundLookup[objectType];
    }

    private void DoThing()
    {
        var sound = this.sound;
        
        // Do something with sound.
    }

    private static Sound Load(string soundPath)
    {
        return new Sound();
    }
}
```

Comment: A problem with this approach is that it's not lazy loading the sounds when initializing the `soundLookup`

Comment: Well, if lazy loading is desired that would be trivial to add.

Comment: The dictionary could be `<ObjectType, string>` and just save the string that needs to be passed to `Load`. Then we just load when needed: `this.sound = Load(soundLookup[objectType]);`

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to have a naming convention with your sound files and `ObjectTypes`, then this becomes a pattern matching issue. For instance, if you define your enums like:

```
public enum ObjectType
{
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,
    Type3 = 3
}
```

Then you can replace your method with:

```
sound = Load($"sounds/sound{(int)type}");
```

Which (for example, type is `Type1`) for the above line would find "sound1"

If you can't setup the values with the enum, but still have numbers in the name itself, you're able to retrieve those numbers by:

```
// Call to replace to get the number, and not the "Type" prefix
string number = Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), type).Replace("Type", "");
```

With the following usage:

```
sound = Load($"sounds/sound{number}");
```

**Edit: Full Example**

```
public enum ObjectType{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}

public class Object{
    public ObjectType type;
    public Sound sound;

    private void DoThing(){
        string number = Enum.GetName(typeof(ObjectType), type).Replace("Type", "");
        sound = Load($"sounds/sound{number}");    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep additional metadata inline with the enum definition, you could build a dictionary based on custom attributes.

```cs
public SoundAttribute : Attribute {
    public string File { get; set; }
}

public enum ObjectType{
    [Sound(File = "sound1")]
    Type1,

    [Sound(File = "sound2")]
    Type2,

    [Sound(File = "sound3")]
    Type3
}

public static Dictionary<ObjectType, SoundAttribute> Sounds = 
    typeof(ObjectType)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .ToDictionary(
        f => (ObjectType)f.GetValue(null), 
        f => f.GetCustomAttribute<SoundAttribute>()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a closer implementation of what I was trying to accomplish.
I think it's at least better than the switch method I was trying to do, but I'm still trying to figure out that enum.

The object type will be manually set no matter what before the instantiation by a dropdown which will be populated each time a new object type is manually created, so I assume an enum is still the best use for this, but I could be wrong.

```cs
    public class MyObject
    {
        public ObjectType type;
        public string soundPath;
        public string otherSoundPath;
        public Sound sound;
        public Sound otherSound;
     
        private void Start()
        {
            type = Self.type;
            soundPath = GetSoundPath(type, false);
            otherSoundPath = GetSoundPath(type, true);
            sound = Load($"\\sounds\\{soundPath}");
            otherSound = Load($"\\sounds\\{otherSoundPath}");
        }
     
        public string GetSoundPath(ObjectType type, bool isOtherClip)
        {
            string soundPath = string.Empty;
            if (!isOtherClip)
            {
                if (!sounds.TryGetValue(type, out soundPath))
                {
                    soundPath = "defaultClip";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!otherSounds.TryGetValue(type, out soundPath))
                {
                    soundPath = "defaultOtherClip";
                }
            }
            return soundPath;
        }
     
        private Dictionary<ObjectType, string> sounds = new Dictionary<ObjectType, string>
        {
            { ObjectType.A, "a" },
            { ObjectType.B, "b" },
            { ObjectType.C, "c" },
        };
     
        private Dictionary<ObjectType, string> otherSounds = new Dictionary<ObjectType, string>
        {
            { ObjectType.A, "a" },
            { ObjectType.B, "b" },
            { ObjectType.C, "c" },
        };
     
    }
     
    public enum ObjectType
    {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }
```